# Stack Overflow Error with Rewired, possible infinite loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

first post so sorry I've I do something wrong
Really struggling with this error, Unity tells me the script but not where specifically, all evidence points to one of my properties (All answers I've seen so far have that problem). But I can't see which one. Pls help D:
Using Rewired for the input

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Rewired;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public static InputManager inputInstance;
[SerializeField] private int playerID = 0;
[SerializeField] public Player soldier = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(0);
[SerializeField] public Player engineer = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(1);
[SerializeField] public Player medic = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(2);
[SerializeField] public Player scout = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(3);

public enum DPadDirection
{
    Up, Down, Left, Right, Null
}

public DPadDirection dPadDir
{
    get
    {
        if(dPadUp)
        {
            return DPadDirection.Up;
        }
        else if(dPadDown)
        {
            return DPadDirection.Down;
        }
        else if(dPadLeft)
        {
            return DPadDirection.Left;
        }
        else if(dPadRight)
        {
            return DPadDirection.Right;
        }
        else
        {
            return DPadDirection.Null;
        }
    }
}

#region Controls Vars

[HideInInspector] public Vector2 movementVector
{
    get
    {
        return new Vector2(GetPlayer().GetAxis("Move Horizontal"), GetPlayer().GetAxis("Move Vertical"));
    }
}
[HideInInspector] public Vector2 lookAtOffset
{
    get
    {
        return new Vector2(GetPlayer().GetAxis("Look Horizontal"), GetPlayer().GetAxis("Look Vertical"));
    }
}

#region DPad
public bool dPadRight
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Menu Right");
    }
}

public bool dPadLeft
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Menu Left");
    }
}

public bool dPadUp
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Menu Up");
    }
}

public bool dPadDown
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Menu Down");
    }
}
#endregion

#region Shoulder Buttons
private float RTValue;
public bool isRTPressed
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetAxis("Shoot") >= .8f ? true : false;
    }
}

private float LTValue;
public bool isLTPressed
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetAxis("Sprint") >= .3f ? true : false;
    }
}

private float RBValue;
public bool onRBPressed
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Reload");
    }
}

private float LBValue;
public bool onLBPress
{
    get
    { //        if xV == 1  true:else:false
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Use Ability");
    }
}
#endregion

#region Other
private float backValue;
public bool onBackPress
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Open Menu");
    }
}

private float aValue;
public bool onAPress
{
    get
    {
        return GetPlayer().GetButtonDown("Menu Select");
    }

}
#endregion

#endregion

private void Awake()
{
    if (inputInstance == null)
    {
        inputInstance = this;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

public Player GetPlayer()
{
    if(ReInput.controllers.GetLastActiveController() == soldier.controllers.GetLastActiveController())
    {
        return soldier;
    }
    if (ReInput.controllers.GetLastActiveController() == engineer.controllers.GetLastActiveController())
    {
        return engineer;
    }
    if (ReInput.controllers.GetLastActiveController() == medic.controllers.GetLastActiveController())
    {
        return medic;
    }
    if (ReInput.controllers.GetLastActiveController() == scout.controllers.GetLastActiveController())
    {
        return scout;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I fixed it! the problem was when I was setting the different Player variables. Although I don't know why

```
[SerializeField] public Player soldier = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(0);
[SerializeField] public Player engineer = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(1);
[SerializeField] public Player medic = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(2);
[SerializeField] public Player scout = ReInput.players.GetPlayer(3);
```

Becomes...

```
public Player soldier
{
    get
    {
        return ReInput.players.GetPlayer(0);
    }
}

[SerializeField] public Player engineer
{
    get
    {
        return ReInput.players.GetPlayer(1);
    }
}
[SerializeField] public Player medic
{
    get
    {
        return ReInput.players.GetPlayer(2);
    }
}
[SerializeField] public Player scout
{
    get
    {
        return ReInput.players.GetPlayer(3);
    }
}
```